# Can sbt help me forking or patching a project?

Tags: git, sbt

I have a dependency on a project that in its newest version has changed a method from public to private. More specifically I'm dependent on Pellet and Jenna where the latest version of Jenna has changed the access to a method that was used by Pellet.

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a patch from within sbt. Meaning, depending on the latest version but then patching it when it's downloaded and my all project is compiled.

If that is a mess, what is the proper way to make a fork in terms of Org Id and Artifact Id and Version Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. sbt is a **build** tool not a version control system where you'd expect having a fork or patch features. Why don't you use a vcs for the use case?

Clone the repo to make a fork and name it whatever you like following the license of the project. I would change `organization` at the very lease so it's clear the library is based upon my fork.

I've just noticed you used [git](/questions/tagged/git) tag for the question so you may also benefit from [the sbt-git plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git) for some part of the use case.